# How should I implement my AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I am making a weather app, where I use AsyncTask for getting response from API and after that setting up the UI. Here how looks like my code now after simplyfing:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    /*
    SOME INSIGNIFICANT CODE HERE
    */

    private fun setUI(currentWeather: Root){
        tv_city.text = "${currentWeather.name}, ${currentWeather.sys.country}"
        /*
        ...
        */
    }

    inner class WeatherByNameTask: AsyncTask<String, Unit, Unit>(){

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?) {
            val city: String? = p0[0]
            val call = weatherApi.getCurrentWeatherByCityName(city!!, API_KEY, "metric")
            call.enqueue(object: Callback<Root>{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Root>, response: Response<Root>) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful){
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Code: ${response.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        val currentWeather = response.body()
                        setUI(currentWeather!!)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Root>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Code: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    inner class WeatherByCoordTask: AsyncTask<Location, Unit, Unit>(){

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Location?) {
            val lat: String = p0[0]?.latitude.toString()
            val lon: String = p0[0]?.longitude.toString()
            val call = weatherApi.getCurrentWeatherByCoordinates(lat, lon, API_KEY, "metric")
            call.enqueue(object: Callback<Root>{
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Root>, response: Response<Root>) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful){
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Code: ${response.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        val currentWeather = response.body()
                        setUI(currentWeather!!)
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Root>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Code: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I'm getting a warning:

> This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur

I want to make it in correct way. I tried to implement it outside the MainActivity class, passing the Context as a parameter, but what's about setUI function? I guess making it public is bad idea.

Comment: Since you're already using Kotlin you should migrate to coroutines including your remote interface since Retrofit also supports coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur

In the `MainActivity`, there are 2 `AsyncTask` class with `inner` modifier, this means the inner class will keep a strong reference to the outer class. The warning tells you while the `AsyncTask` is doing its job in the background, if the user leaves the current activity (press Back key or calling `finish()` method), then the activity instance will be leaked because the `AsyncTask` still keeps a strong reference to it.

**Solution**

Using [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference) to let the `AsyncTask` keeps a weak reference to the `MainActivity`.

```
class WeatherByNameTask (activity: MainActivity): AsyncTask<String, Unit, Unit>(){
    private val activityRef = WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity)

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?) {
        val city: String? = p0[0]
        val call = weatherApi.getCurrentWeatherByCityName(city!!, API_KEY, "metric")
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<Root>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Root>, response: Response<Root>) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful){
                    activityRef.get()?.let {
                        Toast.makeText(it, "Code: ${response.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    val currentWeather = response.body()
                    activityRef.get()?.setUI(currentWeather!!)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Root>, t: Throwable) {
                activityRef.get().let {
                    Toast.makeText(it, "Code: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

class WeatherByCoordTask (activity: MainActivity): AsyncTask<Location, Unit, Unit>(){
    private val activityRef = WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity)

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Location?) {
        val lat: String = p0[0]?.latitude.toString()
        val lon: String = p0[0]?.longitude.toString()
        val call = weatherApi.getCurrentWeatherByCoordinates(lat, lon, API_KEY, "metric")
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<Root>{
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Root>, response: Response<Root>) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful){
                    activityRef.get()?.let {
                        Toast.makeText(it, "Code: ${response.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    val currentWeather = response.body()
                    activityRef.get()?.setUI(currentWeather!!)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Root>, t: Throwable) {
                activityRef.get().let {
                    Toast.makeText(it, "Code: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Use from the activity

```
val weatherByNameTask = WeatherByNameTask(this)
val weatherByCoordTask = WeatherByCoordTask(this)
```

Comment: To make it working, I need to make "setUI()" method public. Is it a good practise to make  such methods public?

Comment: You control the activity and know where to call the public method in right manner, so it's fine to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way how to make `AsyncTask` :

```
private class AsyncTaskGetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AsyncTaskResult<Object>>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected AsyncTaskResult<Object> doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                LibHttp libHttp = new LibHttp();

                String res = libHttp.listBusiness("21","test@ns.com");

                return new AsyncTaskResult<Object>(res);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

                return new AsyncTaskResult<Object>(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<Object> result)
        {

            if(result.getError()!= null)
            {
                showOKAlertMsg("App",getResources().getString(R.string.txt_data_not_found), false);
            }
            else
            {
                String res = result.getResult().toString();

                try {
                    JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(res);

                    if(resObj.getString("status_code").equals("1")){
                        //parse
                        // Do your task here

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showOKAlertMsg("",getResources().getString(R.string.txt_internal_server_error), false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where AsyncTaskResult is

```
  public class AsyncTaskResult<T> 
{
    private T result;

    private Exception error;

    public T getResult() 
    {
        return result;
    }

    public Exception getError()
    {
        return error;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(T result) 
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(Exception error) 
    {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```